# Cannot use Mongoose in a child process?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to utilize the Mongoose library to interact with my database from within a child process like such:

```
process.on('message', function(m) {
    var User = require('./models/user');
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var query = User.findOne({'local.email': 'email@email.com'});
    query.exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) messages.push("Failed");
        messages.push("User is: " + JSON.stringify(user, null, 4));
    });
    process.send(messages);
});
```

This did not work, however, as nothing is printed. I am sure this isn't a problem with logging; what I have discovered is that it only happens when Mongoose is used within a child process. Can anyone explain why this is/how I can fix it?

Comment: Is mongoose in you child process actually connecting to mongoDB (mongoose.connect)?

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing haha... I tried for hours to fix this, no wonder I couldn't find it. Thanks a bunch